# Cohomology group, $H^{2}(X,\mathbb{Z})$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, abelian-varieties

I am reading Chapter I of David Mumford, Abelian Varieties. 
At the beginning of the chapter it is shown the canonical isomorphisms

$H^{2}(X,\mathbb{Z})\cong Alt^{2}(\Lambda,\mathbb{Z})$.

But I would first like to understand the structure of the $H^{2}(X,\mathbb{Z})$, that is the definition.
I did not find it in Mumford, D. Also I looked in Complex abelian varietieis, Herbert and Cristine, without success.

Comment: I suppose $X$ is an abelian variety, but what about $\Lambda$ and $Alt^2$?

Comment: @Cla $X$ is a complex torus, $\Lambda$ is the corresponding lattice and $Alt^2 (\Lambda, \mathbb{Z})$ denotes the group of alternating forms $\Lambda\times \Lambda \to \mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Please add that information —withiut which the question is incomprehensible!—  to the body of the question.

Comment: My question is: what is this set $H^{2}(X,\mathbb{Z})$, where $X$ is a complex torus. The book establishes the isomorphism quoted in my question. But not the definition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$X$ is a compact connected Lie group of dimension $g$, topologically a product of $2g$ circles $S^1$, and
$$H^\bullet (X, \mathbb{Z}) = \bigoplus_{n\ge 0} H^n(X, \mathbb{Z})$$
is the [singular cohomology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_homology) of $X$. It is a graded ring with a "gradedly commutative" product
$$\smile\colon H^p (X,\mathbb{Z}) \times H^q (X,\mathbb{Z}) \to H^{p+q} (X,\mathbb{Z}),$$
called the [cup product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cup_product). Mumford uses the fact that the cup product induces an isomorphism
$$\Lambda^r H^1 (X,\mathbb{Z}) \xrightarrow{\cong} H^r (X, \mathbb{Z})$$
(this is clear for a product of circles, once you know the definition of the cup product) and the first singular cohomology group is then identified as
$$H^1 (X,\mathbb{Z}) \cong \operatorname{Hom} (\pi_1 (X), \mathbb{Z}).$$
Mumford's argument is rather general, and to understand it you may consult any textbook on algebraic topology.

Comment: Thank you. Do you indicate any algebraic topology books?
I still do not understand the structure of the set $H^{2}(X, \mathbb{Z})$

Comment: @Manoel It is an abelian group. Together these groups form the cohomology ring $H^\bullet (X,\mathbb{Z}) = \bigoplus_{n\ge 0} H^n (X,\mathbb{Z})$, with the cup product as the multiplication.

Comment: @Manoel The stuff used by Mumford (the cohomology ring, Künneth formula, etc.) should be in any textbook on algebraic topology. Some people use nowadays Hatcher's book https://www.math.cornell.edu/~hatcher/AT/ATpage.html

Comment: Thank you, I'll look immediately. \o

Comment: @Manoel ...and since you tagged your question as "complex geometry", you may also check the "Principles of Algebraic Geometry" by Griffiths and Harris, it has a section on complex tori.

Comment: Künneth formula is something I also need to understand. In Complex abelian varietieis, Herbert and Cristine is written "Künneth formula implies that $H_{n}(X,\mathbb{Z})$ and  $H^{n}(X,\mathbb{Z})$ are free abelian  groups..."

Comment: I'm also trying to study through Principles of Algebraic Geometry. My goal in fact is to understand Torelli's Theorem! I have a long way to go. thank you